# Insert MAX+1 with Select but insert other values as well

Tags: mysql, select, insert, max

I've seen similar questions but not exactly what I'm trying to do and I can't seem to figure out the exact syntax.

In english I need to do the following:

```
    Column0 = id(primary auto-increment)
    Column1 = interface
    Column2 = subinterface
    Column3 = vlan
```

I want to find the MAX+1 value of the subinterface column, WHERE interface=xyz.  So if this interface 'xyz' already had 5 subinterfaces, the query would insert #6.  At the same time, I want to add more data to this row, like the vlan number that this subinterface will be using (column3).

I'm currently using TWO queries, a "SELECT MAX(`subinterface`)+1 WHERE `interface`='xyz'", and then I take that value and do an INSERT+VALUES to insert the row/newsubint/newvlan.

I'd like to make this entirely one transaction, using just one INSERT that can do this all at once.  I've seen this code referenced many times but I don't see how I can add additional values:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (Column1)
SELECT MAX(Column1)
FROM Table1
```

So my real question is how do I do an INSERT/SELECT and still insert additional VALUES that don't come from other tables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding those other values to the query

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (Column1, Column2)
SELECT MAX(Column1) + 1, 'some other value'
FROM Table1
```

Comment: This is way easier than I though - I kept trying to add a VALUES statement after the SELECT.  Thanks!

Comment: This does not work for MySQL server, it does not allow the same table in INSERT and nested SELECT subquery!